# Has anyone customized the Top Donor Report to have a criterium for total amount given?

Tags: contributions, reports

My users want a list of all the people who have an aggregate donation amount greater than a certain amount.  For example, right now they are asking for a list of people who gave more then $250 cumulatively over the last three years.

Of course, I can run the report and figure out how many people that is and change the number for Show No of Top Donors but then when they want this again in six months you have to do it again.

Comment: possibly unrelated but are you aware of [24/11/15 4:41:05 pm] Peter Davis: https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields and https://civicrm.org/blogs/jamie/progressive-technology-project-release-summary-fields-extension where they explain about the tokens etc

Comment: I think I had forgotten about the summary-fields.  I think my users might really like some of them.  Great suggestion.

Comment: You could also use the aggregate contribution custom search to create a smart group of those donors, which you can then use as a filter in the report/search.

Comment: Hmm, I use custom searches all the time but haven't bothered to look at the ones I don't use in a while.  Nice.  The only downside of this one is you can't specify dates like this year, the last two years, etc. so you can't make a smart group of it.